# Analysis of a time series with a fixed and random factor in R

Tags: r, time-series, anova

I have a dataset which I am not sure how to analyse.

The dataset came from the following experiment: I grew plants (2 different types) and measured their height at different time point (each plant was followed individually). I had in total, 3 boxes in which I grew the plants and, in each box, 3 plants of each type. I took the measurement at 4 different time points.

So, if I am not wrong, the plant type is a fixed factor and the box a random one.

Here is how it is structured:

```
time, box, type, height
1, 1, 1, 1.2
1, 1, 1, 1.3
1, 1, 1, 1.1
1, 1, 2, 1.4 
1, 1, 2, 1.5
1, 1, 2, 1.6
...
2, 1, 1, 1.2
2, 1, 1, 1.3
...
1, 2, 1, 1.2
1, 2, 1, 1.3
```

I would like to know what is the correct way to check if there is a **difference between the different plant types** using R

So far, what I have done is this:

```
lme1 <- lme(height ~ type, random= ~ 1|box, data=mydata)
anova(lme1)
```

but I do not know how to include the time variable in the analysis..

Here is the plot of the height evolution with time, for the different plant type. Each line is a plant.

[image]

Comment: Usually I would use `lme` from the `nlme` package and specify an autocorrelation structure (e.g., using `corARMA`). However, with 4 time points you probably won't be able to fit the autocorrelation. So I would first fit a mixed effects model without autocorrelation structure (probably using package lme4, but you can also use `lme`) and test autocorrelation of the residuals using the Durbin-Watson test, just to be on the safe side. I aggree that plant type (and possibly time) is the fixed effect and box is the random effect.

Comment: @Roland I updated the post with what I have done so far. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Basically. You should also try to include a trend with time (possibly with transformed time to account for non-linear growth) and an interaction of type and time. At first, of course, plot your data and look at the time trends. And test the residuals for autocorrelation.

Comment: @Roland Sorry, I am a newbie in time series, so I have no idea how to include a trend with time... When I look at the plot, it looks quite linear.

Comment: Well, add the plot to your question. Possibly, it might be as simple as `lme2 <- lme(height ~ type * time, random= ~ 1|box, data=mydata)`. You could also try to model autocorrelation using something like  `lme2c <- lme(height ~ type * time, random= ~ 1|box, correlation=corARMA(0.2, form=~time|box, p=1, q=0)`, data=mydata)` and test `anova(lme2, lme2c)` if the autocorrelation parameter can be estimated by the model (which is unlikely with such short).

Comment: @Roland Here is the plot. When I try the autocorrelation, as you suggested, I got the following error: `covariate must have unique values within groups for "corARMA" objects`

Comment: Do you have several values (plants) per box and time point? Then you might need a nested random effect.

Comment: @Roland yes, I have 6 plants per boxes, 3 of each type. And a time point for each one of them.

Comment: Then you need a nested random effect: `~1|box/plant`. E.g., `lme2c <- lme(height ~ type * time, random= ~ 1|box/plant, correlation=corARMA(0.2, form=~time|box/plant, p=1, q=0), data=mydata)`

Comment: @Roland Thanks it worked this time. The test `anova(lme2, lme2c)` returned a p-value < .0001

Comment: Then look at the AIC and use the better model.

Comment: @Roland Thanks for everything. Will you post our comments as an answer or shall I do it?

Comment: I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For mixed-effects modells of time series I usually use the `nlme` package, because it offers facilities to model auto-correlation structures. If I don't need to consider auto-correlation, I prefer the `lme4` package, which offers more flexibility for specifying random effects and is also usually faster.

I recommend reading Zuur et al. 2009 (ISBN 978-0-387-87457-9) as an introduction to mixed effects modelling with R. The book contains a lot of nice and illustrative examples using the `nlme` package.

From your question and comments the structure of your model should be as follows:

- **fixed effects:** intercept, plant type (make sure that this is a factor variable and not a numeric in R!), time and the interaction between both
- **random effects:** random intercept grouped by plant nested within box, possibly also a random slope vs. time with the same nesting structure
- **correlation structure**: some kind of  auto-regressive moving average correlation structure with time as a co-variate and the same grouping structure as the random effect

Thus, a full model could look like this: `fit1 <- lme(height ~ type * time, random= ~ 1|box/plant, correlation=corARMA(0.2, form=~time|box/plant, p=1, q=0), data=mydata)`. You should test by comparing models using the `anova` function if including a random slope improves the model. You should also test, which auto-correlation structure is most appropriate (although Zuur et al. advise against spending too much effort on finding the optimal auto-correlation structure). Of course, you also need to study residual plots. Possibly you might need to specify a variance structure or transform the dependent if the model suffers from heteroskedasticity. Judging from the plot the relationship between height and time is pretty linear, but you could also try to transform time.

Potential problems: You have an extremely small number of time points, which could result in problems when trying to fit the auto-correlation parameter(s). It could even be impossible to fit them. Also, your number of individuals and boxes is very small.