# Auto-correlation vs. number of observation periods

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures, autocorrelation, random-effects-model

I've just read an excellent post
[mix model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71087/analysis-of-a-time-series-with-a-fixed-and-random-factor-in-r)

I've a question connected to that. Can you recommend any reference to a comment that if one have not enough observation periods then it is difficult to model properly auto-correlation? Did I understand it properly, that four observation periods are probably not enough to successfully account on auto-correlation.

Comment: Four observations are barely enough to model anything.

Comment: I meant four observation periods not four observations

Comment: For hierarchical model, you can estimate whole covariance matrix, of which autocorrelation is a special case. In econometric applications, specifically panel data, small $T$ is a classical case. See Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data by J. M. Wooldridge.

Answer (score 2):

4 time points is not necessarily a problem for handling autocorrelation. The `lme` function in the `nlme` package has several methods which may be appropriate such as `corAR1` for fitting an AR(1) process

Edit to adddress @whuber's comment:

I can see why the question could seem a bit vague. I took it to mean that, in the context of a mixed effects model used for a longitudinal study, a number of participants say, $N$, are measured 4 times each. Of course there are many more than 4 observations in total ($4N$ obviously, if there are no missing data). I think that is where the OP was making a distinction. A single time series of length 4 would be hopelessly inadequate for estimating an AR(1) model, but with many participants, this is a common model to fit, either in a mixed model framework or an SEM (for example. latent growth curve models and extensions thereof) - at least it is common in lifecouse epidemiology where the previous measurement often has a large influence on the next measure, compared to the other covariates, even with just 4 time points. BMI is a good example of this. Perhaps the estimated AR(1) coefficient still does not have a desirable level of precision but I have seen such models where they offer an improved interpretation as well as a better fit. Without the AR(1) process in the model, the covariances between residuals at each time point can be unrealistic.

I prefaced my answer with "not *necessarily*" because, of course it might be too few time points particularly if the level of autocorrlation is small (and hence my example in lifecourse epidemiology where it can be quite large). I may be able to find a toy dataset to illustrate this, if interested.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "4 time points"?  It reads like you're referring to a time series of length four, but it would be almost impossible to estimate any autocorrelation coefficient with enough precision for AR modeling in that case. The OP appears to make a distinction between "observation periods" and "observations," although it isn't evident what that distinction is.

Comment: @whuber, sure, I have edited the question to respond to your comment

Comment: Very illuminating, thank you!